# Having problems getting border radius and gradient on a header of a table at the same time

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

**UPDATE : NOW IT WORKS IN CHROME AND NOT IN FIREFOX**

I cant get a border radius and and a gradient on the header of the table at the same time.

```
//normal table
<table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class ="header">
        <th>one</th><th>two</th><th>three</th><th>four</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr><td>onetd</td><td>twotd</td><td>threetd</td><td>fourtd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>onetd</td><td>twotd</td><td>threetd</td><td>fourtd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>onetd</td><td>twotd</td><td>threetd</td><td>fourtd</td></tr>
</table>
```

css that is not working. the gradient was taken from some gradient generator

```
    tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color: yellow;
    }
        tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: green;
    }
    table thead tr.header{
            border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border:1px solid black;
         background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(52,156,235) 19%, rgb(61,224,216) 60%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(52,156,235) 19%, rgb(61,224,216) 60%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(52,156,235) 19%, rgb(61,224,216) 60%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(52,156,235) 19%, rgb(61,224,216) 60%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(52,156,235) 19%, rgb(61,224,216) 60%);

        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
          linear,
          left bottom,
          left top,
          color-stop(0.19, rgb(52,156,235)),
          color-stop(0.6, rgb(61,224,216))
        );
    }


table thead tr.header > th:nth-child(1){
border-top-left-radius:10px; 


}
```

I would definitely like it to work in major browsers

not working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6WqV/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css:

```
.border{
            border: 2px solid #666666;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
        }
        table {
            margin: 50px;
            border-spacing: 0;
            width: 450px;
        }        
        .border th:first-child {
            border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        }

        .border th:last-child {
            border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        }

        .border td:first-child, .border th:first-child {
            border-left: medium none;
        }

        .border th {
            background-color: #666666;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #3DE0D8, #349CEB);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#3DE0D8), to(#349CEB), color-stop(.4, #3DE0D8));
        }

        .border td, .border th {
            border-left: 2px solid #666666;
            border-top: 2px solid #666666;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even){
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        tr:nth-child(odd){
            background-color: green;
        }
```

html:

```
<table class="border">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><label>one</label></th>
                <th><label>two</label></th>
                <th><label>Three</label></th>
                <th><label>Four</label></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>one</label></td>
                <td><label>two</label></td>
                <td><label>Three</label></td>
                <td><label>Four</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>one</label></td>
                <td><label>two</label></td>
                <td><label>Three</label></td>
                <td><label>Four</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>one</label></td>
                <td><label>two</label></td>
                <td><label>Three</label></td>
                <td><label>Four</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>                    
    </table>
```

Comment: I like what you did, thank you for your work. it's just that in the jsfidle that i am posting in this comment I've made some minor changes in your code and ive noticed that  it works in chrome and not in firefox. what I mean by not working is that there is green bkgrnd coming out of the TH where the corners was. it seems that the color that is coming from the first tr in the tbody is extending into the thead. If just the 3rd tr is green and the first one is not, the green wont be in the thead. I wonder why. u could see for your self in the browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/aUjFd/

Comment: i have updated the code in your mentioned jsfiddle link, have a look on it.http://jsfiddle.net/aUjFd/2/

Comment: Thank you. This got the job done. I would like to keep this question open for a bit to see if someone has another way of doing it. If not than i'll choose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect name for the property it is border-top-left-radius not border-radius-top-left and you need a border to apply a border radius to.

Comment: set the container div on the thead?<div><thead></thead></div>>

Comment: sorry @user2537537 I didn't realise you were trying to apply to thead, check my latest update

Comment: thanks for the correction but i still cant get a border-top-left-radius on the header. thanks anyways

Comment: you can't apply it to a thead nor can you wrap a thead in a div tag. What I have done in the past is have the thead separate to the table.

So have two tables:

<div class="headerBorder">
<table>this is your header table</table>
</div>
<table>
this is your content table
</table>